# Can the Nilakantha Series be represented in sigma notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The highest math class I ever completed was algebra 1 and that was in 2015... I probably do not have the conceptual understanding to tackle a problem like this, so bare with me if the things I say and the words I use are wrong and/or stupid. I wanted to have a simple, exact mathematical definition of pi, with no dots implying the infinity steps following the pattern of numbers before them. That just seems messy and uncharacteristic of math.

Nilakantha series: $$3 + \frac{4}{(2*3*4)} - \frac{4}{(4*5*6)} + \frac{4}{(6*7*8)} - \frac{4}{(8*9*10)}$$ ...

It calculates the decimal expansion of pi.

Sigma seemed like a way to do this. However, I looked it up and no matter how I worded my question, I couldn't figure out if there was a proper, syntactically correct way to A. add 3 to the final sum, and B. change how the index is affected after each iteration. For example, if I wanted to increase i by two each iteration instead of 1. To reproduce the Nilakantha Series, I would also need to subtract terms as well as add them. I decided to create my own notation, in the hopes that it could be translated by someone more knowledgeable into something legitimate.

However, despite my improper syntax, I think I was successful. I compiled everything as neatly as possible with photoshop.

[Nilakantha Series in My Sigma Notation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kfv8.png)

For the record, I have no purpose for this. I just really like playing with numbers.

Comment: Please include in your question a definition of the Nilakantha series.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I included it in the picture. It'll look ugly in text but I'll do it.

Comment: There is information on this site on how to format mathematics nicely. Try the help menu.

Comment: So, you want $$3+\sum_1^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}{4\over2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}$$?

Comment: Yeah I think that's right, you'd know better than me for sure, but I get what I expect when I plug numbers in. I see how much I over complicated alternating between addition and subtraction. The denominator is much more simple too. I had n(n+1)(n+2) essentially at one point, I guess I confused myself trying to change how sigma works.

Comment: So, Kyle, I have posted an answer. Is there anything more that you need?

Comment: No, I apologise for not accepting your answer more swiftly. I'll add that while this post was less eventful than I was hoping for, I fearfully anticipated harsh responses regarding how I attempted this problem. I'm sure it was cringe worthy. Rather, I got my answer, understood it, and I learned about the math formatting so I can perhaps produce a higher quality, unrelated question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what OP wants is $$3+\sum_1^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}{4\over2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}$$